# Backbone.js - Properties vs Attributes

Tags: backbone.js

What is the difference between properties and attributes of a Backbone model.

I believe one would use attributes to trigger model changes when the model gets modified.

In the below example.

```
var Vehicle = Backbone.Model.extend({prop1:'1'});
var v1 = new Vehicle({prop1 : '1111'});
console.log(v1.prop1); // accessing the property
console.log(v1.get('prop1')); // accessing the attribute
```

The object `v1` has both a property called `prop1` and also an attribute called `prop1`. There is no relation between them.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is really that a property is a language feature (Javascript), whereas an attribute is a feature of the Backbone framework.  To put it another way, a property exists independently of Backbone, whereas an attribute relies on the Backbone framework and its infrastructure.

Specifically, attributes participate in all the model-related things:

- sync (when you call `save` or `fetch`)
- validation on save
- view rendering (via `toJSON`)
- events and notification